# sequelize - is it possible to use findByPk when Primary key is composite key?

Tags: sequelize.js, composite-primary-key, findby

I have model called session with composite key of three properties: seesionId, userNameId and accountId.
In order to create new record I need to check if there's already session with the same userNameId and accountId.

the API of findByPk:
public static async findByPk(param: number | string | Buffer, options: object): Promise

I don't understated how to pass userNameId and accountId together.

**SESSION MODEL**

```
export class Session extends Model<Session> implements ISessionModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataType.UUID)
    sessionId: string;

    @PrimaryKey
    @IsUUID(4)
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataType.UUID)
    accountId: string;

    @PrimaryKey
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    userNameId: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    userName: string;
..
..
}
```

Comment: As far as I know Sequelize doesn't support composite primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

The docs does not specify a way to do that, but lists the ways you can find records through sequelize: (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html)

I had to use `findOne` instead of `findByPk`

This is on plain javascript, where we try to find a record for a model with composite keys:

```js
const res = await db.MyModel.findOne({
  where: {
    entityOneId: args.entity_one_id,
    entityTwoId: args.entity_two_id,
  }
});
```